# Delete the input file after GhostScript finishes converting to PDF

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

Can someone show me how to use the PostScript `deletefile` operator to delete the input file after GhostScript finishes converting the input file to a PDF file.

Comment: "(/path/filename) deletefile". Note that current versions of Ghostscript will refuse to perform this operation unless you either run with -dNOSAFER (**NOT** recommended) or add --permit-file-all=/path/filename to the command line. This is a security measure to prevent PostScript programs interfering with disk contents without explicit permission.

Comment: @KenS - Thanks for the response. I seem to be having a hard time getting the syntax/punctuation right. <code>"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.55.0\bin\gswin64c.exe" -q -dNOSAFER -sDEVICE#pdfwrite -o "C:\Temp\Temp_0001.pdf" -c (C:/Temp/Temp_0001.ps) deletefile -f "C:\Temp\Temp_0001.ps"</code>. Additional help would be greatly appreciated. I will remove the -dNOSAFER after I get the other portion working!

Comment: nvm - I think I got it. I had to switch the -c and the -f switches (and arguments) around. However, it does seem that DOS/Windows style path specifications "C:\Temp\Temp.ps" are not acceptable to the deletefile operator, but C:/Temp/Temp.ps or even C:\\Temp\\Temp.ps seem to work Ok. Any workaround to that?

Comment: No. IIRC this is due to the command shell processing, '\' is seen as an escape. You either need to double up '\' so the command shell decreases them to 1 or use Unix style line endings. It's not PostScript or Ghostscript doing it, it's Windows. Your command line is missing quotes "" round the content between -c and -f. Also the input is processed in order, so the -c...-f is processed before the input filename. That means it will delete the file, then try to process it. I'm sure you don't mean that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to work for me, first creating the PDF file, then setting the permissions on the input file, and finally deleting the input file.

```
"C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.55.0/bin/gswin64c.exe" -q -sDEVICE#pdfwrite 
 -o "C:/Temp/Temp_0001.pdf"
 -f "C:/Temp/Temp_0001.ps" 
 --permit-file-all=C:/Temp/Temp_0001.ps 
 -c (C:/Temp/Temp_0001.ps) deletefile
```

**NOTE**: Since I had to switch to Unix-style path separators (even though I am running this on Windows) for the `permit-file-all` and the `deletefile`, I decided to use the same convention for both the output and input files as well. Windows seems to be OK with that, and the convention was uniformly used for all paths/files.